# Use $.ajax() in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf

Is there a way to call a method in Java using $.ajax() without using f:ajax tag? I've seen many tutorials uses f:ajax tag but I'd like to use pure ajax because I need to dynamically create DOM and call AJAX after that.

JQuery

```
var url = "insert.jsf"; // Assuming insert() action is called.
var data = {};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("ERROR");
    }
});
```

PersonController.java

```
// I think an annotation should be placed here.
    public void insert() {
       // Do something.
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to handle all complicated JQuery operation and AJAX by hand without using f:ajax. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I'll find another way to do it.